# How to set the default path/directory to the directory where the session was started?

Tags: tmux

I'm using an old version of tmux (v1.5).  How can I configure tmux to set the default directory to the directory where the session was started?

This isn't a problem with newer versions of tmux (1.7 and later).  I can simply add the following to `~/.tmux.conf` to get what I want:

```
set-option -g default-path "-"
```

Unfortunately this option isn't available in the version of tmux I am using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted, but it works:

- Add this function definition to your `~/.profile`:

  ```
  tmux() ( ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX="${PWD}" command tmux "$@"; )
  ```

  This function runs `tmux` with the environment variable `ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX` set to the current directory (`${PWD}`).  This variable will be referenced whenever a new window is created.
- Add the following to your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

  ```
  set-option -g default-command "[ -z \"\${ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX+set}\" ] || { cd \"\${ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX}\"; unset ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX; }; exec ${SHELL}"
  set-option -g -a update-environment " ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX"
  ```

  The above `default-command` value checks to see if the `ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX` environment variable is set.  If so, it changes to that directory and unsets the variable (to keep the environment clean).  It then invokes the shell, which will run in the original directory.

  The `update-environment` setting tells `tmux` to copy the value of `ORIG_PWD_FOR_TMUX` into the session environment so that future `new-window` commands will have the variable value available.

Now you can simply run `tmux` as usual except that new windows will start in the same directory as the session.